# Client side encryption for braintree payments

Tags: java, javascript, payment-gateway, payment-processing, braintree

I am working on client side encryption for braintree payments. With out encryption the application runs fine, but when i encrypt the card number using client side encryption (braintree-1.1.0.min.js), card number encrypts (into a long string) but i get error as response saying

> (Credit card type is not accepted by this merchant
>   account. Credit card number must be 12-19 digits. CVV must be 4 digits
>   for American Express and 3 digits for other card types)`

I am using 4111111111111111 as card number provided on braintree site.

[Brain Tree site.](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/java/reference/sandbox)
On server side i am usng Java.
Thanks in advance for helping...

Comment: Is client side encryption enabled for your account?

Comment: @techfoobar thanks for your response, I am new to brain tree, can you kindly help to how to enable encryption.

Comment: See this link: https://www.braintreepayments.com/braintrust/client-side-encryption - In the section "Creating the Keypair" - you'll see that you need to enable it for your account to be able to generate the keys needed for encryption. Secondly CSE is still in public beta, you probably will need to contact them to enable it. See last sentence in above article for contact info.

Comment: @techfoobar Thank you so much for you respones, encryption is enabled and i have the key pair combination.

Comment: I work at Braintree. Since this is probably a configuration problem rather than a code problem, you should consider reaching out to `support@braintreepayments.com` so we can help you track down what's wrong in detail. You can also reach us on the phone at 877.434.2894 or check out our support page at https://www.braintreepayments.com/support

Comment: @agf thank you so much for your response, i have contacted the support team and hopefully i will get response to solve my problem soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work at Braintree.

Generally, this error indicates you've either used the wrong key, or you've somehow modified the encrypted strings before sending them to us.

Your javascript should look something like:

```
var braintree = Braintree.create("MIIB...")
```

where the string is your client-side encryption key, which is very long -- much longer than your merchant id, public key, and private key.

If you include your code, both client-side javascript and server-side Java, I might be able to spot the specific issue you're having. Please *don't* include your private key if you add your server side code.

Comment: Dumb question: Does the Sandbox accept the encrypted data as-is, or do I need to say somehow that "the data in this field is encrypted"? I experience the same headaches. (Using your comment on JS, I located added whitespace, though.)

Comment: @olleolleolle It automatically detects the encryption, as long as it's enabled for your account -- which it is for all account created in the last year and a half. The best way to get help if you're having integration problems is to reach out to [our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/), but also feel free to ping me here.

Comment: Aaaaand, done. Many of my troubles with Braintree has only been me underappreciating amazing features that were far more powerful than the docs let on.

Comment: @olleolleolle Glad it worked out. Let us know if there is anything else we can do to help.

Comment: @agf   do we need to enable this client side encryption now also? my account is just created., I working on php for thw server side,but my credit card is not getting accepted when using encrption but without encryption everything is working fine. Please help me asap, thank you so much

Comment: I am using ios on client side and php + yii framework on server side.